# Count distinct instances of a SKU and count all items in all instances containing that SKU

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, count

This is on MSSQL/Azure SQL.

I have the following Sales Table:

| Line_Item_ID | Sales_Order_ID | SKU |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 | 7 |
| 6 | 3 | 4 |
| 7 | 4 | 4 |
| 8 | 5 | 1 |
| 9 | 5 | 8 |

I am trying to get an output that shows for each SKU, the total number of Orders (very easy) AND the total number of line items for an Order that contains that SKU.

So for the first part:

```
select SKU, count(distinct(sales_order_id) as "Order_Count"  from Table T
group by SKU
```

Easy enough, however the second part is doing my head in -

The desired output would look like this:

| SKU | Order_Count | Line_Item_Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 7 |
| 4 | 4 | 7 |
| 7 | 1 | 3 |
| 8 | 1 | 2 |

How do I get a count of the total Line_item_IDs for each order that contains a SKU? Ideally in a single query without a load of crazy joins or subqueries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a **window function** with the `COUNT()` function in a **CTE** or **subquery** to get the total `Line_Item_ID` count per `Sales_Order_Id` or even just group it separately at that point, and re-join it to your existing query with a `SUM()` on top of it to get the total `Line_Item_ID` for each `SKU` like so:

```
WITH CTE_LineItemsPerSalesOrder AS
(
    SELECT sales_order_id, COUNT(1) AS LineItemsPerSalesOrderCount
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY sales_order_id
)

SELECT T.SKU, COUNT(DISTINCT(T.sales_order_id) as Order_Count, 
    SUM(C.LineItemsPerSalesOrderCount) AS Line_Item_Count
FROM Table T
INNER JOIN CTE_LineItemsPerSalesOrder AS C
    ON T.sales_order_id = C.sales_order_id
GROUP BY T.SKU
ORDER BY T.SKU
```

Feel free to rename and reformat the casing of the syntax I used, as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on available indexes and size of data, you may find this useful

```
SELECT
    x.Line_Item_ID, 
    x.Sales_Order_ID, 
    x.SKU
INTO #x
FROM
(
    VALUES
        (1, 1, 4),
        (2, 1, 1),
        (3, 2, 4),
        (4, 3, 1),
        (5, 3, 7),
        (6, 3, 4),
        (7, 4, 4),
        (8, 5, 1),
        (9, 5, 8)
) AS x
(Line_Item_ID,  Sales_Order_ID, SKU);


SELECT
    x.SKU,
    COUNT_BIG(DISTINCT x.Sales_Order_ID) AS OrderCount,
    SUM(l.SaleCount) AS LineItemCount
FROM #x AS x
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT
        COUNT_BIG(*) SaleCount
    FROM #x AS x2
    WHERE x.Sales_Order_ID = x2.Sales_Order_ID
    GROUP BY x2.Sales_Order_ID
) AS l
GROUP BY x.SKU
ORDER BY x.SKU;
```